# Mail using php 5.6 (xampp 1.8.3 - window 8)

Tags: php, email, ssl, sendmail, phpmailer

help me : I am not send mail using `phpmailer + php 5.6` . 
How to fix mail ?

error alert

> SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP ru8sm9096361pbb.20 - gsmtp
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO php.local
>   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [1.55.98.150]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>
> Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in D:\www\PHP\mail\PHPMailer-master\class.smtp.php on line 338
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>
> SMTP connect() failed.
>   Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPMailer - SSL3\_GET\_SERVER\_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827192/phpmailer-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

PHP 5.6 introduces SSL certificate verification, so if your config is broken, it will fail with this error. You should fix your SSL, but you can revert to the old behaviour by overriding PHPmailer and passing these options to the `smtpConnect` function:

```
$options = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```