# Error openssl when sending email via PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, ssl

When I tried to sending email from gmail using PHPMailer, I have a trouble with certificate of OpenSSL. How could I fix that?

```
2015-10-30 17:12:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2015-10-30 17:12:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in....location folder.
2015-10-30 17:12:22 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2015-10-30 17:12:22 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-10-30 17:12:22 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
2015-10-30 17:12:22 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: This might be helpful: [PHP 5.6 certificate verification failure](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#user-content-php-56-certificate-verification-failure). Also see [certificate verify failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827192/phpmailer-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed).

Comment: I had fixed this. Tks a lot!

Comment: It is recommended to post your answer and accept it to close this question properly and let others benefit from it.