# How to fix: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: email, ssl, gmail, cygwin, phpmailer

I am currently working on cygwin.
I was trying to send and email through phpmailer using my gmail account and the following script (obtained online, then hacked):

```
 <?php  
 require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
    try {
        $mail->ISSMTP();
        $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
          'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => true,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
          )
        );
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "MyGooglePassword";
        $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'my name1');
        $mail->addAddress('anotheremail@email.fr', 'my name2');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Exceptions test';
        $mail->Body = "Hi, This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
        $mail->send();
        echo "Message sent!"; 
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
```

I have seen multiple solutions on stack overflow, but I haven't found any telling how to properly self sign my localhost so that I would be able to avoid this error message:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /usr/share/pear/phpmailer/class.smtp.php on line 346
2015-11-30 08:47:15     SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2015-11-30 08:47:15     CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-11-30 08:47:15     SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed
```

I have also tried resolving the issues by setting 'verify_peer' to false at "$mail->SMTPOptions" (as recommended in: [PHPMailer - SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827192/phpmailer-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed)), but when I do that, my gmail account refuse to cooperate saying that the signing attempt does not meet modern security standard!!

Please let me know if there is a proper tutorial that would allow me to properly set my ssl and have the email successfuly sent with the proper verifications.
Here is below a link to the gmail message: [Gmail - sign in attempt prevented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Bk1.png)

Comment: Gmail's certs should not fail verification. It may be that your root certs are out of date and need [updating](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).

Comment: @Synchro. I attached a picture of the gmail sign in attempt prevented. Also thank you for the link provided. I checked it and from it I could certify that I had the latest cacert.pem. I assigned its location in my php.ini to the variable: "curl.cainfo". Shall I have added it somewhere else as well?

Comment: Ah. I thought you were seeing that in the SMTP response. That just means you need to either enable less secure apps or implement xoauth2, as per the docs.

Comment: @Syncro I tried enabling xoauth2 using the following link: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2 the only thing is that as I was running a script directly on the CLI, I used "other" (which provided me an oauthClientId and an oauthClientSecret) instead of "web application", but I got the same error message. To the above code, I added 4 new variables: $mail->AuthType,  $mail->oauthUserEmail, $mail->oauthClientId and $mail->oauthClientSecret. Did I forget something? Or is it possible that the error was caused by something else?

Comment: You need to look at the SMTP transcript (`SMTPDebug = 2`) and see what it says. It may be that you need to log in via the web as the google message says as they may have blocked your account temporarily.

Comment: Debugs does not provide much information. But tanks to our conversation, I was able to send an email through my yahoo account to my gmail, so I think I will be good for now. It was not absolutely necessary that I send through gmail. I just wanted to understand why it failed. And thanks to you I think I did. I will be closing this as resolved. Thanks a lot for your help in this Synchro.