# PHPMailer fails after upgrade from PHP 5.5 to 7.1.4

Tags: ssl, phpmailer, php-7.1, phplist

Specifically we fail with this message:

```
[30-Apr-2017 14:05:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailer-5.2.8/class.smtp.php on line 272
```

Googling this we find reports of similar errors during upgrades from PHP 5.5 - but these all stem from improved certificate verification introduced in PHP 5.6.  This doesnt seem to be our issue.  For instance - following the [PHPMailer troubleshooting wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) - we are able to connect to the smtp server with openSSL.

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect vps.ourserver.com:587
.
.
SSL handshake has read 5284 bytes and written 468 bytes
.
.
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Turning SMTBDebug on (level 4) doesn't really show anything useful:

```
2017-04-30 16:04:54     CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-04-30 16:04:54     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-04-30 16:04:54     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 TLS go ahead
                                          "
2017-04-30 16:04:54     SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2017-04-30 16:04:54     SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-04-30 16:04:54     CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

As stated - this problem started immediately after the PHP upgrade. No changes to code or SSL/Certificate configurations.

Suggestions on next steps to troubleshoot?

Edit: It was suggested that this question may have been [solved previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827192/phpmailer-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed) SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE.. but it is a different error message (and I did try overriding the smtpoptions as suggested - to no effect).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer - SSL3\_GET\_SERVER\_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827192/phpmailer-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed)

Comment: You ignored the *very first thing* the troubleshooting guide says - you're running a very old, buggy and vulnerable version, so you should update it to the latest before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Upgraded to PHPMailer 5.2.23 and the error message disappeared.  Thanks to Synchro (despite the snarky tone...lol).